# yarn - install modules in a specific directory

Tags: yarnpkg

When I do `$ yarn install`, I see that `./node_modules` directory gets created and modules are installed in that directory.

I also get that `--modules-folder ./directory_location` exists, to install in a specific directory one time.

Is there an option to always use a specific directory to install in package.json configuration?

Answer (score 20):

I am now using `scripts` to do this.

And I can run `yarn run newinstall`

In package.json

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "newinstall": "yarn install --modules-folder ./directory_location"
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: It still also creates ./node_modules, but it only contains .bin folder.

Answer (score 8):

Create a `.yarnrc` file in your root project folder, along side, `package.json`.

Inside of `.yarnrc`, add the following:

```
# install modules here
--modules-folder apps/my_cool_application/static/

# Note: target directory goes after `--modules-folder` {{target dir}}
```

In this example, running `yarn install` will install all modules into `./apps/my_cool_application/static`, so for example,

Bootstrap, after being installed would live in: `./apps/my_cool_application/static/bootstrap`

Note: If your `node_modules` folder currently exists, you can delete it after creating `.yarnrc` and run `yarn install` for all your packages to be downloaded again into your targeted directory.

[This site had a helpful walk through](https://www.caxy.com/blog/how-set-custom-location-nodemodules-path-yarn), and offers some additional information.

Comment: It still creates a ./node_modules every time I run the Yarn command, but installs it at the correct location.

Answer (score 1):

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cd subdirectory && yarn install", //exec after yarn install automatically
}
```

Comment: If you use this code, yarn will install to `subdirectory/node_modules`, and `postinstall` run if someone install your module https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#description